Plotly highlight function highlighting incorrect boxplots
While my cursor above the boxplots displays the correct statistics, the higlight function can only highlight one of the boxes and doesn't work correctly. Wherever I click, the leftmost box is higlighted:

I tried doing a test with the iris dataset, and the problem persists:
I <- iris

I %>%
  highlight_key(~Species) %>%
  plot_ly(y = ~Sepal.Length, x = ~Species, type = "box", layout = "overlay") %>%
  highlight(
    on = "plotly_click",      
    off = "plotly_doubleclick", 
    dynamic = TRUE)

How can I highlight another box that just the leftmost?

A solution would be to set selectize = TRUE in the highlight() function.
library(plotly)

I <- iris

I %>%
  highlight_key(~Species) %>%
  plot_ly(y = ~Sepal.Length, x = ~Species, type = "box", layout = "overlay") %>%
  highlight(
    color = "green",  
    selectize = TRUE,
    dynamic = TRUE)

This way, you can select each specie box plot, and by pressing the Shift key on your keyboard, you can select more than one box plot at the same time.

Hope it helps!
